# Position of a record within an index

Tags: database, delphi, indexing

If I have an index within a table, is there a way to locate the relative position of a record?
example, there are 5 records displayed:

1
4
5
6
7

then on locating value=5, is there a way to know 5 is the 3rd record in this index?

then what if there is a filter applied - my guess is when there is a filter applied, definitely have to loop through every record to find the position... so maybe there's still a chance to know if it is simply Index deployed (without filter).

thanks.

*edited* Purpose: to show a progress bar on position of this record relative to first and last record. thanks.

Comment: No, there's no way to do what you're asking other than to start at the top of the table and count rows until you reach the one you want. This number would change any time the index order was changed or a new row was added prior to the row you want, which means it's not reliable at all. If it was clear what your need was for this, there might be another way to accomplish it, but I can't tell from your post what you're actually trying to do. You can tell a filter is in effect by checking the dataset's `Filtered` property - if it's `True`, a filter is in effect.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  If you are talking about the database's index then you should not be concerned with it or rely on it because how the database implements it's indexes is up to the database.  If, instead, you are referring to how displayed records are sorted and shown within your application then that's a different matter entirely.  How are you storing the records in your application, how are you sorting them and how are you displaying them?

Comment: My intention is just to show a progress bar depending on how far away the record is from the first record relative to the last record.  Thanks for the confirmation this cannot be done.

Comment: Depending on the TDataset implementation, the `RecNo` property gives some indication of the position of the record in the dataset.

Comment: @R.Hoek is this RecNo accurate for TFDDataset, and MySQL and Sqlite in particular?

Comment: @PeterJones I do not know, as I’ve never used TFDDataset and/or MySql/Sqlite. But with TAdoQuery it is (when I do not use the dataset filter).